# L'emploi adj. du part. présent du verbe "enfumer"

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, littérature

Bonjour,

Pourriez-vous m'aider à comprendre le sens de l'emploi adj. du part. présent du verbe "enfumer" dans ce cas ?

"Et je vous raconte pas tout!... Je m'embouillonne de rage d'y penser... je **m'enfumante**... je m'égare rien que d'en causer!... au souvenir!..." (CÉLINE, 2015, p. 112)

Le verbe est-il employé dans le sens de "troubler l'esprit" ? "chercher à tromper, à mystifier, par des paroles ou des actions dilatoires" ?

Pourquoi est-il au féminin si le narrateur du roman est un homme ? Merci d'avance !

Comment: Encore une fois on ne peut que spéculer devant cette création Célinienne. D'un point de vue grammatical je réfute le terme de « participe présent » et « d'emploi adjectival » pour *enfumante*. Je vois le verbe « s'enfumanter » à la première personne du sing. du présent de l'indicatif. Verbe bien sûr qui est une création de l'auteur, à partir de enfumer  → avec modification orthographique. Pour quelle raison cette modification ? Il faudrait le demander à l'auteur. Évoquer la construction du participe présente pour montrer l'action  en train de se dérouler ? Faute de frappe ? Pures spéculations.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 3):

On ne peut que spéculer devant cette création Célinienne. D'un point de vue grammatical dans « je m'enfumante » il ne s'agit pas d'un participe présent employé comme adjectif  mais j'y vois le verbe « s'enfumanter » à la première personne du singulier du présent de l'indicatif. Verbe qui est bien sûr une création de l'auteur, à partir de « s'enfumer » et avec modification orthographique. Pour quelle raison cette modification orthographique ? Il est possible que seul l'auteur puisse répondre. Ceci n'empêche pas de spéculer à loisir. Peut-être une faute de frappe, peut-être une construction qui est employé sciemment pour rappeler l'aspect du participe présent, qui exprime une action en train de s'accomplir.

Answer (score 1):

On ne trouve pas ce verb dans la langue standard. Il s'agit très probablement d'un mot inventé par Céline sur la base du verbe « enfumer » de sens figuré, et de l'adjectif « *fumant* », de sens figuré aussi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enfumer)) **enfumer** **3**. Au fig. [En parlant de l'ivresse ou de ce qui grise] Troubler l'esprit.
> ♦ L'absinthe bue un soir d'hiver Éclaire en vert l'âme enfumée (Cros, Coffret Santal,1873, p. 28).
> ♦ Un cerveau enfumé d'opium.  (Huysmans, À rebours,1884, p. 84)
> − P. métaph. Enfumer qqn d'encens. Griser par des compliments excessifs (cf. J. de Maistre, Corresp., 1814, p. 125).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fumant)) **fumant** **C**. − Au fig.
> **1.** [En parlant d'une pers.] Bouillonnant, excité, échauffé. Fumant de colère.

Cet usage de « enfumanter » pourrait n'être qu'une reprise de « Je m'embouillonne de rage », dont le verbe, encore probablement une des  inventions de Céline, est conçu à partir du verbe « bouillonner », lequel peut être  associé à une idée de colère dans la langue standard.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bouillonner)) **bouillonner** **2**. Au fig. Être en effervescence. Bouillonner de fureur, de colère. ,,Être agité de fureur, d'une violente colère`` (Ac. 1835-1932)
> ♦  Quels que pussent être les sentiments qui bouillonnaient dans mon âme, je jugeai qu'il y avait lieu de prescrire la suspension d'armes pour autant qu'on tirât encore et, tout en maintenant les positions acquises, de ne pas nous opposer aux mouvements que les troupes britanniques entreprendraient de leur côté. De Gaulle, Mémoires de guerre,1959, p. 191.

Le préfixe « en » (« em » avant un b) est ajouté pour changer le verbe intransitif en un verbe transitif qui signifie « se porter (selon un procédé plus ou moins rapide) à l'état décrit par le verbe intransitif » ; soit les deux verbes  signifient donc fondamentalement « se mettre en colère », soit le premier seulement signifie cela et le second signifierait « s'intoxiquer, se troubler l'esprit » ; cette dernière possibilité tend à être confirmée par ce qui suit dans le texte, c'est à dire « je m'égare », ce que l'on peut très bien comprendre comme « je perds la tête », « j'y perds mon bon sens ».

Comment: @None Ma copie de Guignol's Band montre ceci : « Je m'embouillonne de rage d'y penser ». Il y a donc des problèmes d'édition.  Cette édition électronique du livre Guignol's band I / Guignol's band II [Le pont de Londres] de
Céline a été réalisée le 26/07/2011 par les Éditions Gallimard.

Comment: L'édition de la Pléaide donne : "Je m'embouillonne de rage d'y penser" (CÉLINE, 2015, p. 112).

Comment: @ovide La Pléiade c'est fiable, je n'ai qu'une version numérisée aussi et les deux font sens (enfin si on peut dire...). Comme il y avait une faute de frappe sur le m→n je n'ai pas cherché plus loin.

Comment: @None En fait ça tombe bien, il y a bien une erreur à corriger.